# opengeo-suite upgraded from 3.0 to 3.1 on Ubuntu and I can't start GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite

I'm having trouble starting GeoServer after updating all of the opengeo-suite applications via apt-get update, apt-get upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade.

GWC works, the dashboard is there as is geoexplorer. I can see geoserver in Tomcat's application manager, but I get a 404 tomcat error when I go to /geoserver.

Log file is here: http://pastebin.com/TdnYRxAZ

catalina.properties here: http://pastebin.com/acJCpAsa

Comment: note: in my case, this only happens after an update. If one uninstalls the `opengeo-suite` and then reinstalls the new version, there is no such behaviour. (OS: Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I resolved it by renaming the folder `/usr/share/opengeo-suite/geoserver` to `/usr/share/opengeo-suite/geoserver_OLD`.

I'm not very experienced with tomcat, but I think that it was looking in that folder before the geoserver.war in order to start things up.

I don't know how it got like that, but now geoserver works again! (yay)

Comment: works fine to get the geoserver web access back but disables extensions like the ImageMosaic JDBC which rely on the original file path (JARs in `/usr/share/opengeo-suite/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/`)

Comment: Ok this is actually not a problem. I figured out that in OpenGeo 3.1 they changed the plugin folder from `/usr/share/opengeo-suite/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/` to `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib`. Just move your non-default JAR files there and everything works like before.

Answer (score 1):

The log is saying that the folder

```
/usr/share/tomcat6/server/
```

does not exists. Maybe when you update the distro something was moved o removed.

Check your tomcat installation.